# Dragged Row Becomes Invisible When Moving Between Google Chart Tables in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I am experiencing an issue with Google Chart tables in a WordPress environment where a row becomes invisible when I drag it from one table to another. The dragged row does become part of the new table (as the rows adjust based on the cursor position), but it's not visible during the drag action. Additionally, scroll bars appear unexpectedly in the table when a row is dragged.

Here's a snippet of my code for creating sortable tables:

```js
function makeTableSortableTeams(tableDivId)
{
    $("div[id^='table_teams_div']").each(function () {
        var currentTable = '#' + $(this).attr('id') + ' tbody';
        $(currentTable).sortable({

            helper: function (e, tr) {
                var originals = tr.children();
                var helper = tr.clone();
                helper.children().each(function (index) {
                    $(this).width(originals.eq(index).width());
                });

                helper.css({
                    "background-color": "rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.8)", 
                    "border": "1px dashed black",
                    "cursor": "move",
                    "position": "absolute",
                    "overflow": "visible",
                    "z-index": 10000 
                });

                return helper;
            },
            start: function (e, ui) {
                ui.helper.css('z-index', 10000); 
            },
            stop: function (e, ui) {
                
            },
            connectWith: "div[id^='table_teams_div'] tbody",
            receive: receiveHandler
        }).disableSelection();
    });
}

function receiveHandler(event, ui)
{
    var receiverTable = $(this).closest('.table-teams-container');
    var senderTable = ui.sender ? ui.sender.closest('.table-teams-container') : receiverTable;

    var receiverId = receiverTable.attr('id');
    var senderId = senderTable.attr('id');

    var senderGroupId = senderId.replace('table_teams_div', '');
    var receiverGroupId = receiverId.replace('table_teams_div', '');

    var movedData = {
        Verein: ui.item.find("td:first").text(),
        Team: ui.item.find("td:nth-child(2)").text()
    };

    updateGroupsData(senderGroupId, receiverGroupId, movedData);
}

function updateGroupsData(senderGroupId, receiverGroupId, movedData)
{
    console.log("Sender Group ID: ", senderGroupId);
    console.log("Receiver Group ID: ", receiverGroupId);
    console.log("Receiver Group ID: ", groups);
    console.log("Sender Group Data: ", groups[senderGroupId]);
    console.log("Receiver Group Data: ", groups[receiverGroupId]);
    if (!groups[senderGroupId] || !groups[receiverGroupId]) {
        console.error("Eine der Gruppen existiert nicht:", senderGroupId, receiverGroupId);
        return;
    }

    var senderIndex = groups[senderGroupId].Verein.indexOf(movedData.Verein);
    if (senderIndex > -1) {
        groups[senderGroupId].Verein.splice(senderIndex, 1);
        groups[senderGroupId].Team.splice(senderIndex, 1);
    }

    groups[receiverGroupId].Verein.push(movedData.Verein);
    groups[receiverGroupId].Team.push(movedData.Team);
}
```

The issue occurs in a WordPress environment, and I suspect it might be related to CSS styling or the interaction between JavaScript and the DOM. The tables are created dynamically with Google Charts, and the rows are made sortable using jQuery UI.

Questions:

1. What could be causing the dragged row to become invisible during the drag action?
2. How can I prevent the unexpected appearance of scroll bars in the table when a row is dragged?
3. Can I somehow "encapsule" the "working area" or set an invisible overlay over the whole page as "new parent", when dragging?

I have already tried `z-index` and setting the overflow of all elements to `visible`.

Comment: Are the scrollbars showing only on `dragStart` and do they disappear on `dragEnd`? What happens if you zoom your page out quite a bit, and test your dragging then? Is the scrollbar still there? The reason I'm asking this - perhaps your dragged element is being translated (for some reason) out of view, and your content container is stretched because of it.

Comment: The scrollbars appear, when the dragged element is moved to the bottom of the table, or to the right side. Only if I try to move it out of the table. They disapear when I stop dragging the element.